# Why only one electron is emitted from gas present in vacuum tub in anode ray experiment

Tags: particle-physics

My teacher told me that in anode ray experiment the electron were emitted from the gas present inside the vacuum tube and the ionized electron form cathode ray and ionized gas form anode ray. So I wanna know thus atoms present inside the vacuum tube were fully ionized and only their nucleus remain? So for my bad English.

Comment: Wikipedia has a table with ionization energies: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energies_of_the_elements_(data_page) It contains data for multiply ionized ions of the lighter elements. As you can see the necessary energy to strip inner electrons off grows quite quickly. This means that fully stripped nuclei of heavier elements can only exist in very hot plasmas.

Answer (score 0):

If by "fully ionized" you mean all electrons stripped off, no, the rest of the bond electrons stay and the atom from neutral becomes a positive ion.

Unless it is hydrogen gas where the nucleus is a single proton and can be fully stripped off from its electron.